# django_mailgun.MailgunBackend does NOT send Django's errors via email

Tags: logging, http-status-code-400, django-mailgun

I had an issue trying to send Django's Errors via email. Mailgun's logs are completely empty for this domain!

Hacking django_mailgun.py revealed <Response 400> from mailgun which fails silently.

Why django_mailgun.py does not work ?

Answer (score 3):

When `SERVER_EMAIL` is not defined in `settings.py`, Django sends errors from `"root@localhost"` which does NOT work for Mailgun anymore and produces <Response400>

So i have added:

```
SERVER_EMAIL = 'postmaster@my-domain.com'
```

to settings.py